# Change location of the Dash icon to the top of the panel

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, gui, customization, gnome-dash

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Wondering if there is a way to change the location of the Dash icon AKA start menu, from the bottom side to be at the top side of the Dock panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top true
```

Use the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top
```

to reset to default.

In Ubuntu, the setting is not exposed to the user. In the original Dash to Dock Gnome-shell extension, on which "Ubuntu Dock" is based, the setting is exposed in the settings dialog.

Comment: thanks so much worked smoothly, no reboot was needed.
is there any course or tutorial that might lead me to a good level in ubuntu?